# Getting fingerprint of certificate signing request

Tags: openssl, fingerprint, csr

I am aware that I can get the fingerprint of an x509 certificate by typing
`openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -noout -fingerprint`

But if I try to get the fingerprint of a CSR (`openssl req -in certrequest.csr -fingerprint`) I get

> `req: Unrecognized flag fingerprint`

As I understand it, the fingerprint is of the key used, so I ought to be able to get it from a .csr file. How can I do that, besides creating a custom script? Or have I misunderstood some key concept?

Comment: Please check the help of the x509 mode: `-fingerprint: Print the certificate fingerprint`. Of course that will not work on a cert request as the certificate is not yet issued.

Answer (score 0):

Researching the hyperweb after taking a longish break bears fruit:

From [ldapwiki](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Certificate%20Fingerprint)

> Certificate Fingerprint is NOT part of the Certificate but rather the hash of the DER encoded certificate

According to that definition, I ***cannot*** get the fingerprint of a csr, because it is NOT a certificate. My understanding that it was a hash of the key was erroneous, which makes sense...

Comment: Some X.509 certs put hash of publickey in the SubjectKeyIdentifier extension (and SKI value of issuer in AuthorityKeyIdentifier), although CSRs don't need to since CA can calculate it at issue, and it's not called fingerprint. For comparison PGP uses hash of publickey as fingerprint and its 'low'/rightmost octets as key-id in the protocol, and OpenSSH uses hash of publickey as fingerprint in the UI (but it is not used in SSH protocol).

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the fingerprint of any piece of data.

Example command for a CSR:

```
openssl req -in example.csr -outform DER | openssl dgst -sha256 -c
```

Comment: This is not the "fingerprint", this is just the message digest, i.e. the hash of the file. From the question and the OP's self-answer, they really were looking for the "fingerprint" of the file (even though they couldn't get one based on the tool).

Comment: @schroeder - are you sure I am wrong? I do not think so but I do want to learn more since I have been working in PKI for decades. To quote: `a fingerprint, is a hash of a certificate, computed over all certificate data and its signature.` Published example using OpenSSL for CSRs: https://redkestrel.co.uk/articles/openssl-commands/#fingerprint

Comment: "You can calculate the fingerprint of any piece of data." -- yes, but that's not a fingerprint in the ***context*** the OP is asking for.

Comment: @schroedern - The question is `Getting fingerprint of certificate signing request`. I provided the method to calculate the fingerprint of a CSR. That is what was asked and I provided a solution. Feel free to post another solution. BYW: the statement in the self-answer is wrong: `I cannot get the fingerprint of a csr`.

Comment: So, after all these comments, you should rewrite your entire answer to be more on point and to offer a correction. "You *can* produce a signature of a CSR by outputting the CSR and signature as a DER then running a hash on it like this ..." Right now, it's a generic comment with an unexplained command with no explanation of how a hash is a signature in context of the question.

Comment: @JohnHanley I agree that any file or piece of text can be hashed, and in theory if I can figure out which hashing algorithm the vendor is using and which parts of the csr to include in their fingerprinting algorithm, I could pipe that to the digest function in openssl as you do in your answer.

Comment: Maybe I should elaborate on my question, because this is based on a real world example with a known vendor using certificates and CSR that fingerprints the uploaded CSRs. My issue was that I had to re-upload the same csr, but i did not know which it was. My solution was to upload several CSRs until i found the right one. unfortunately that part would expose a lot of details, hence the rather vague and broad question

Comment: Now you know how to generate a fingerprint for a CSR. If you know the byte length of their fingerprint, you can guess the algorithm. For example, MD5 is 16 bytes long, SHA-1 is 20 bytes, SHA-256 is 32-bytes. The command in my question can be modified to generate any supported algorithm. Just change the `-sh256` flag.

Comment: This is the way to generate the fingerprint of a request in the same way that is shown in the Puppet Enterprise unsigned certificates list.